# strange behavior with randint in python

Tags: python-3.x, random

```
rol_dict = { 0: "value 1", 1: "value 2", 2: "value 3" }

def rol_rand():
    global rol_list
    return rol_dict.get(randint(0, 2))

rol_rand()

if rol_rand() == rol_dict.get(0):
    print("value 1")
elif rol_rand() == rol_dict.get(1):
    print("value 2")
elif rol_rand() == rol_dict.get(2):
    print("value 3")
else:
    print(rol_rand())
    print("rol don't exist")
```

For this code some times appear this output

```
value 1
rol don't exist
```

why???

Why does this behavior occur and what alternatives exist?

Comment: Probably you only want to get _one_ random roll, instead of one you ignore and one for each condition that's not met. Do some debugging, e.g. https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with the fact that you actually call `rol_rand` multiple **different** times, and since it returns a random number every time, there is not guaranteed consistency.

Your current program gets a random number between 0 and 2. If it's not 0, it rolls a **new** random number, checks if its 1. If not it gets a **new** random number again and checks if its 2. It's somewhat likely that you get 3 values that don't correspond to their checks.

In order to fix this, you just need to store the roll in a variable like so

```py
from random import randint

rol_dict = { 0: "value 1", 1: "value 2", 2: "value 3" }

def rol_rand():
    return rol_dict.get(randint(0, 2))

saved_roll = rol_rand()

if saved_roll == rol_dict.get(0):
    print("value 1")
elif saved_roll == rol_dict.get(1):
    print("value 2")
elif saved_roll == rol_dict.get(2):
    print("value 3")
else:
    print(saved_roll)
    print("rol don't exist")
```

Comment: Actually up to _five_ different times.

Comment: Correct - I originally wrote 5 but it was only 3 (or perhaps 4) "significant times"... Now I just changed it to "multiple" :)